# Any way to trigger a Cron error using PHP?

Tags: php, cron

I am creating a cronjob in cPanel that runs a simple PHP script.

If my CronJob fails then the server automatically sends me an email which is good, but how can I trigger this error from my PHP script?

Is there a way like with exit() or similar?

Comment: what do you mean trigger the error? If it errors, it errors .. :S

Comment: You could log the error from your PHP, if you're not logging them already.

Comment: [`trigger_error ( string $error_msg [, int $error_type = E_USER_NOTICE ] ) : bool`](http://php.net/trigger_error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly [`exit`](https://php.net/exit) from the program and pass a valid exit status that is not 0 so that cron will recognise it as exiting in an error state.

```
fwrite(STDERR, "This is a fatal error!" . PHP_EOL);
exit 1;
```

Comment: What's that syntax of `warn` ?

Comment: Ughh, poor dude! :D